# Adding a text input to a form

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I want to add an input to a form and cannot make it work. When loading the page, clicking "submit" and looping through the $_POST array, no input was added to the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    $('#myOrder').append('<input type="text" name="test" value="product">');
    </script>
    <form id="myOrder" action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    if ($_POST)
        {
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
            {
            echo $key . "<br>";
            echo $value;
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Help is highly appriciated!

Comment: where do you call the script?

Comment: Did you include JQuery?

Comment: @Jon Mark Perry. I put the append() in a function on an external file and call the function with addEventListener on load.

Comment: @Vucko. Not sure what you're on about.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your code inside `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myOrder').append('<input type="text" name="test" value="product">');
});
```

Comment: Thank you Hamed. Shokran. Sorry for the late reply, I was grabbing a bite. I did not think append() had to be called as it was inside the body of the document.

Comment: You are welcome. It's better to put my code inside `<head></head>` section.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm,
You can try make inputs as array like this;

```
$('#myOrder').append('<input type="text" name="input[]" value="product">');
```

GL